# is it possible to show only the label of a single data in a chart?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, charts

I am currently using a Microsoft Visual Studio.

I have my line chart with some datas and I'd like to show a label of a **unique** data. Instead of to show all labels (`Chart.Series("series1").isvalueshownaslabel = true`)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Label` property of an individual `DataPoint`

```
Chart.Series["series1"].Points[0].Label = "The y value is #VAL";
```

There are several keywords (like #VAL) that can be used to fill in point-specific values, just search the MSDN documentation.